# NSUserdefaults works on Simulator but not on Device

Tags: xcode, nsmutablearray, nsarray, nsuserdefaults

I would like to save an `NSArray` to `NSUSerDefaults`. If I do it on Simulator everything works, if I do it on Device, it doesnt work.

```
NSArray *Test1 = [Daten copy];
NSArray *Test2 = [Kosten copy];

[prefs setObject:Test1 forKey:@"Daten"];
[prefs setObject:Test2 forKey:@"Kosten"];
```

I am using the above code.

`prefs` is a normal `NSUserDefaults`, like `NSUserDefaults *prefs = [NSUserDefaults standartUserDefaults];`...

Daten & Kosten are Mutable Arrays, to work with.

Everything works on simulator, but on device it doesnt work...

Does anybody have an idea?

Answer (score 0):

Are you synchronizing them after settings/updating ?

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
```

Comment: yes its important.. put this after "[prefs setObject:Test2 forKey:@"Kosten"];" and see if you are able to get the data back from nsuserdefaults

Comment: no, nothing changes... damn, why does it work on simulator but not on device?!?

Comment: well, could it be because of ios5? i am programming with xcode 3.2.5 and ios4 on simulator, but ios5 on device...

Comment: In iOS4 or above, your User Defaults may not get saved when pressing the home button. Manually calling [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize] in applicationDidEnterBackground: should ensure that your User Defaults are saved correctly (this should really be a built-in behaviour IMO).

Comment: hi, i solved it :-) it was my fault... i made a resigntofirstresponder of a textfield, befor the saving process... so he just didnt save it and resignedtofirstresponder.... the crazy thing is... on ios 4 it worked ;-) thank you for all your help... you can close this or delete it because i think it got no interesting stuff in it :-)

Comment: it would be great if you can post your answer on SO .. it will help someone someday!

Answer (score 0):

Because Saurabh asked me to post my solution, I will do it for other readers.

My Problem Code was the following:

```
[derText1 resignFirstResponder]
[derText2 resignFirstResponder]

NSArray *Test1 = [Daten copy];
NSArray *Test2 = [Kosten copy];

[prefs setObject:Test1 forKey:@"Daten"];
[prefs setObject:Test2 forKey:@"Kosten"];
```

This worked on an iPhone 4 Simulator with XCode 3.2.5 but not on my Device with iOS 5.x installed.

So I have downloaded and installed the newest XCode version from Apple.

After that it also doesnt work with the Simulator too. It looks like the problem is only with iOS 5 Software.

Than I changed my code simply to that:

```
NSArray *Test1 = [Daten copy];
NSArray *Test2 = [Kosten copy];

[prefs setObject:Test1 forKey:@"Daten"];
[prefs setObject:Test2 forKey:@"Kosten"];

[derText1 resignFirstResponder]
[derText2 resignFirstResponder]
```

And it worked on Device and Simulator with the latest iOS. Take a look at the position of the resign First Responder Entrys. They seem to have to be after the saving. I don't know why, but it works.

Answer (score 0):

```
NSArray *Test1 = [Daten copy];<p>
NSArray *Test2 = [Kosten copy];<p>


NSUserDefaults *prefs;<p>
prefs= [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]setObject:Test1 forKey:@"Daten"];<p>

[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];

prefs= [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]setObject:Test2 forKey:@"Kosten"];<p>

[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
```