# NSUserDefaults saves / loads on simulator but not on device

Tags: ios, objective-c, save, load, nsuserdefaults

I am doing an iphone game and saving data using NSUserDefaults. Here is how I save a user:

```
-(void) saveUser:(User*)user forPosition:(int) position{
NSData *myEncodedObject = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:user];
NSUserDefaults*savedData=[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
[savedData setValue:myEncodedObject forKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"user%i",position]];
[savedData synchronize];
self.currentUser=user;}
```

And here is how I load it:

```
-(BOOL) loadUser:(int) position{
if([savedData objectForKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"user%i",position]]){
    NSData *encodedObject = [savedData objectForKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"user%i",position]];
    User *user = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:encodedObject];
    self.currentUser=user;
    return YES;
}
else return NO;}
```

As you can see, I am saving a custom class on NSUserDefaults. To do that I used guidance from [How to store custom objects in NSUserDefaults](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2315948/how-to-store-custom-objects-in-nsuserdefaults) (in case anyone is interested).

When I use this in the simulator it works perfectly. The problem is that if I run this on my iphone (iphone 6 on ios 8.1) it doesn't load anything.

Any ideas of what it could be? I've already visited this question [NSUserdefaults works on Simulator but not on Device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8455460/nsuserdefaults-works-on-simulator-but-not-on-device) but nothing worked. 
Thanks!

Comment: You could just print all contents of your NSUserdefaults and check. Maybe also put it in the question here.. Here is how to do it http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1676938/easy-way-to-see-saved-nsuserdefaults#1848980

Comment: Thanks, by printing the content I found what was wrong and I could fix it. The problem was that the (int) position was receiving a wrong number (I don't know why and I don't know why on the simulator it worked correctly) and therefore it saved the user with another key. I found a way around this problem. Thanks

Comment: Just added the same as answer. Maybe you could accept the answer. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess there could be some problem saving it.

Check what exactly is being saved.
You can print the complete `NSUserDefaults` using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1676938/easy-way-to-see-saved-nsuserdefaults#1848980)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setObject instead of setValue ?

```
[savedData setObject:myEncodedObject forKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"user%i",position]];
```